# Present modal while transitioning to the previous view

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, modal-dialog

When I leave a particular view controller, I want to have it display a modal view over the previous view in the navigation stack.  Currently I'm doing it with this code:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    self.navigationController?.viewControllers.last?.present(myModalView, animated: false, completion: nil)
}
```

This *seems* to work, but every time I leave the view I get a warning in the console:

`Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged <Project.MyViewController: 0x7fe09281a400>.`

So I'm concerned that there might be a problem I haven't run into yet.  Is there a "correct" way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, `self.present(myModalView, animated: false, completion: nil)` works perfectly with no warnings.  In retrospect, I probably should have tested that first, but I had assumed it wouldn't work since the view was disappearing.

Additionally, it **does not** work at all with `animated: true`, whereas my original solution **does** with no warnings (but I don't want it to be animated).  Not sure if that's just how the asynchronous processes work out or if there's something more to it.

Answer (score 0):

You are presenting the modal on the current view controller, not over the previous view controller. When you do

```
self.navigationController?.viewControllers.last?.present(myModalView, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

in the `viewWillDisappear` protocol, it's the same as saying

```
self.present(myModalView, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

Instead, try this:

```
let previousVCIndex = self.navigationController?.viewController.index(of: self)
self.navigationViewController?.viewControllers[previousVCIndex! - 1]?.present(myModalView, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

Comment: That looks like it will do exactly the same thing.  It finds the index of the current view controller in the navigation controllers list of view controllers and then gets that view controller from the list and presents the new view with it.

Comment: I don't think this is the case, since the warning message showed the correct class name and the navigation stack during that function showed the previous view controller as `.last`.  But in any case, I stumbled on the solution while testing this so thanks anyway ;)

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth you are correct, I meant to subtract 1 from the index, thanks! My answer has been updated.